# In a large data set, identify which variables are categorical and which are numeric

Tags: r

I have a list of 65 variables, and I want to separate out the lists of numerical and categorical variable.

What can be command for this task.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `split` with `sapply` to group the variables together:

```
split(names(iris),sapply(iris, function(x) paste(class(x), collapse=" ")))
$factor
[1] "Species"

$numeric
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

Note the use of `paste` to collapse together any multi-class object's class names.

Comment: Thanks James, it gave the result I wanted.

Comment: Never use `sapply()` with class: this will fail as soon as you have time variables in your data frame.

Comment: Thanks @hadley, I've made an edit to make to solution more robust to issues with multi-class variables.

Comment: @Rahul for variables that have only one class. The extra stuff I added helps protect against multi-class variables.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this (imagine your data.frame is named `df`) :

```
sapply(df, class)
```

Indeed, the output with time variable is less pretty :

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(V1 = character(10),
                 V2 = numeric(10),
                 V3 = ymd(paste("2014-05", 21:30, sep="-")))
sapply(df, class)
##$V1
##[1] "factor"
##
##$V2
##[1] "numeric"
##
##$V3
##[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

But it still work to identify numeric or factor variables like if there was no time variable :

```
names(df)[sapply(df, class) == "factor"]
##[1] "V1"

# for time variable it's less obvious indeed...
names(df)[grepl("POSIXct", sapply(df, class))]
##[1] "V3"
```

Comment: Never use `sapply()` with class: this will fail as soon as you have time variables in your data frame.

Comment: Thx for the comments, I already had this issue... what do you suggest to use? `mode`?